# What is efficient way to read stale data in Spanner using node or java client?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-spanner

our use case allows to read stale data (between 10 to 15s) so exploring staleness read using node or java client. In node we have `Database.getSnapshot` or `Database.runStream(sql, option)` -option we can mention different staleness strategy.

`Snapshot` - we can have database, table, transaction snapshot, but database snapshot does not accept any option where as transaction snapshot accept option for Timebound.

My question is which way is effective way to read stale data?

1) using Database.getSnapshot or table.getSnapshot or transaction.getSnapshot?

2) using Database.runStream(sql, option) with max, exact staleness

### Update

In node, I followed example mentioned in the link https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/spanner/latest/Snapshot.html#Snapshot-examples. and my code as follows

```js
const timestampBounds = {
        strong: false,
        maxStaleness: 15000
      }
      databse.getSnapshot(timestampBounds, async (err, trans) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }

        const [qOneRows] = await trans.run(query)
        //resolve(qOneRows);

        trans.end();

      } );
```

I am getting below error

```
{ Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Bad BeginTransaction request.
  at Object.exports.createStatusError (/workspace/session-monitoring/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
  at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/session-monitoring/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1204:28)
  at InterceptingListener._callNext (/workspace/session-monitoring/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
  at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/session-monitoring/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
  at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/session-monitoring/node_modules/grpc-gcp/src/index.ts:155:13)
  at InterceptingListener._callNext (/workspace/session-monitoring/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
  at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/session-monitoring/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
  at callback (/workspace/session-monitoring/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24)
code: 3,
metadata:
 Metadata {
   _internal_repr:
    { 'google.rpc.badrequest-bin': [Array],
      'grpc-status-details-bin': [Array],
      'grpc-server-stats-bin': [Array] },
   flags: 0 },
details: 'Bad BeginTransaction request.',
note:
 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }
```

My spanner version is "@google-cloud/spanner": "^4.0.2"
Node version is v10.11.0

Comment: I have updated the answer with the correct API. Please try out Database.run() or Database.runStream().

Answer (score 2):

For java client, you can use following methods of [DatabaseClient](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/spanner/DatabaseClient.html) with a [TimestampBound](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/spanner/TimestampBound.html) instance.

- singleUseReadOnlyTransaction()
- singleUse()

For node.js, you can use [Database.run()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/spanner/latest/Database.html#run) or [Database.runStream()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/spanner/latest/Database.html#runStream) with timestamp bound options.

Please note that above are strictly for read only case.

Comment: please refer my question updated part for the issue that i having with Node snapshot

Comment: in num-3 config, if read with or without timestamp bound options the query latency stays same on non-indexed column. i expected see with timebound should do better and should give consist latency but that is not the case

Comment: Could you elaborate your scenario with query snippet?